# java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null when trying to insert to Telephony.Sms.Conversations

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

Can't *insert* a new conversation to **Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI**.
Keep getting a **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null** exception.
Even though the uri has a value of **"content://sms/conversations"**.

### Situation - logic flow

I receive an SMS message from an unknown number.
I insert a *conversation* for the unknown number (if one not found).
I insert the *message* and associate it with the newly created *conversation*.

### Dev setup

For learning purposes, I am creating an Android SMS application with Kotlin.
*Android Emulator* with *Pixel XL API 26*.
The application I'm working on is set as the *default SMS app*.
Can successfully send, receive and *insert (code below)* individual messages.

### createMessage() - works

Below is the working code I wrote to insert a message when the phone receives an SMS.

```
fun createMessage(
    resolver: ContentResolver,
    threadId: Number,
    body: String,
    sentByUs: Boolean
): Message? {
    val messageType = if (sentByUs) Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT else Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID, threadId.toInt())
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, body)
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.TYPE, messageType)

    val result = resolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, values)

    return this.getMessage(resolver, result)
}
```

### createConversation() - doesn't work

Below is the code I'm working on which tries to insert a new conversation.

```
fun createConversation(
    resolver: ContentResolver,
    senderPhoneNumber: String,
    latestMessageText: String,
    latestMessageTimestamp: Long,
    latestMessageIsOurs: Boolean,
    latestMessageWasRead: Boolean
): Conversation? {
    val wasRead = if (latestMessageWasRead) 1 else 0
    val isOurs = if (latestMessageIsOurs) Telephony.Sms.Conversations.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT else Telephony.Sms.Conversations.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX

    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.ADDRESS, senderPhoneNumber)
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.BODY, latestMessageText)
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.DATE, latestMessageTimestamp)
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.TYPE, isOurs)
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.READ, wasRead)

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ------ Throws java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null ------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    val result = resolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI, values)

    return this.getConversation(resolver, result)
}
```

While executing the *resolver.insert()* the application crashes with the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null

With the debugger attached I can see that the uri *does* have a value.
*Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI*  is  **"content://sms/conversations"**

### How does Google do it?

Found out that Google open sources its common Android apps.
Here's the code for the *Messaging* application:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/

While analyzing **DatabaseHelper.java** I came to the conclusion that they create a whole separate database from scratch.
And then work with that troughout the lifetime of the application.
Which confused me even more - why don't they use *resolver.insert()*?
I may be wrong, the program was overwhelming for a new guy like me.

## Question

If *Telephony.Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI* has a value of *"content://sms/conversations"*, why do I get the exception?

Comment: On Which phone model you get exception?

Comment: @Amir Hossein Ghasemi, the phone I emulated was the Google Pixel XL (API 26).

Comment: Recently I see this only on one phone Xiaomi Mi Mix5 that user get `uri must not be null` while he has the uri. I couldn't fix it not till now, If I could, will inform you

Comment: Same issue on a Pixel 3XL running Android 9. Did anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Hello @AmirHosseinGhasemi ... did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi, @BrookMG I just checked my old messages and it seems I couldn't fix that issue. it seems there was an issue storing messages. are you still getting this issue from your users?

Comment: Yes @AmirHosseinGhasemi, noticing the issue on Pixel 3 and other low-budget phones like Techno, currently disabling the component if this issue shows up on the device.

Answer (score 1):

To investigate such issue you need to turn off logcat filtering for your app. Then you'll find an SQLiteException that will help find out what's actually wrong.

The NPE refers to the fact that the insert failed and return a null Uri instead of the appropriate Uri path of the new element.